# Roboto based fonts not showing up in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, angular-material, roboto

I have an angular material application which when viewed in IE (11) doesnt display the fonts correctly. In Firefox and Chrome I dont see any problem.

The fonts are not being fetched remotely, they are contained as resources within the application.

As an example I have a sidenav component that holds a menu which looks like this in Chrome\Firefox:

[image]

But in IE looks like this:

[image]

Inspecting the network traffic in IE I can see the font files are being successfully retrieved and I can open these just fine when copying the urls into a new browser tab.

Oddly when I run protractor tests against IE, the fonts are rendering fine, I wonder if selenium server\IEdriver are doing something differently that allow the fonts to display?

Anyone got any ideas what could be the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, set up the IE dev tool to record dev console messages first... Tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes... when you now open the dev tool to debug your web pages the Console tab will list markup, blocked content and security warnings and messages... IE has security zones... you can find out which IE security zone a domain is mapped to from the File>Properties menu in IE. Perhaps localhost is incorrectly mapped to the intranet zone.